# Firebase data payload not delivered when app is in Doze on Wear OS

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, wear-os

We have a Wear OS app, which relies heavily on Firebase messages. We send **data only** messages from **pyfcm** and we handle them inside `onMessageReceived()`. All messages are with **high priority**. This seems to be working properly for some time, which varies - can be between 10 minutes and few hours.

After some time we stop receiving messages. From the documentation I know that a high-prio data message should wake up the device even in Doze - unfortunately this is not happening.

What we believe it is happening is that FCM is de-prioritizing our notification because of low interaction pattern. The issue is that his is core functionality and we can't change that.

Any idea how we can overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that the problem is that FCM is de-prioritizing your messages. The problem could be how your app is handled by Wear OS when in Doze mode.

A similar issue is present in android smartphones. They don't receive push notification from FCM when user swipes the app from the system tray because, due to brand specific battery saving reasons, the services needed to handle push notification (MessagingService and InstanceIDService) are not running in the background. To have an idea of the issue on smartphone see this: [Firebase Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/41).

Probably after some time that your app is in background it gets killed by the OS in order to save battery, so then the services are not running and it doesn't receive notification anymore.

**Anyway without some further explanation on how the app works and without any code I can only make a guess.**

Comment: We created a simple test case - a simple app, which implements `onMessageReceived()` and a simple script which is sending **data** message every minute. While the watch stays on (I can see the watchface), `onMessageReceived()` is called normally. As soon as the watch goes into idle mode (I listen for `ACTION_DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED`) the service is not called every minute. It get's called in the maintenance window or when I wake up the watch. Indeed the watch has OEM batt optimization app, but I have excluded/protected/whitelisted my app ...